# How to map a function name back to the macro with clang frontend?

Tags: c++, macros, clang

I'm using the clang front-end to parse my code and need some help with macros. Given this trivial example:

```
#define CreateFile CreateFileA
struct Test
{
    virtual void CreateFile() = 0;
};
```

I get a FunctionDecl from my ASTVisitor, but FunctionDecl->getName() returns "CreateFileA". How can I figure out that it was originally "CreateFile"? I assume something with the clang::Preprocessor class will help.

Thanks.

Comment: I did it once, can't remember exactly how. I remember it has to do with getting the location of the start and end of the name and then those locations contain information on whether they are from a macro expansion and which.

Comment: Was there not some discussion similar to this just a little while back on the cfe-dev mailing list [which is archived for searching!]

Comment: Thanks - I found this that helped me out. [link](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-dev/2012-February/020005.html)